# Do --VIrtual-time-budget still work at Chrome 106.0.5249.119?

Tags: google-chrome-headless

At Chrome 87,when I add --Virual-time-budget, the process will wait util all of the js load
but when I use Chrome 106.0.5249.119,this arg seems not working anymore. The Chrome  process will stop within 1s, no matter what is the real situation of my page loading.

Question is, why --Virual-time-budget is good in Chrome 87 but not good in Chrome 106? What's the different between them? How can I make the browser to wait until my page loading is done?

My command is below:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome \
--headless \
--disable-gpu \
--no-sandbox \
--ignore-certificate-errors \
--log-level=0 \
--disable-dev-shm-usage \
--start-maximized \
--window-size=1920,1080 \
--virtual-time-budget=300000 \
--enable-logging=stderr \
--v=1 \
--enable-features=NetworkService \
--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process \
--disable-web-security \
'http://nginx/ngsoc/REPORT/api/v1/set-cookie-and-redirect?cookies=auto_report=1;access_token=RJtApMMmLP5SAqmjJ7lkNkEP6FA&redirectUrl=aHR0cDovL25naW54OjgwLyMvcmVwb3J0L3JlcG9ydF90ZW1wbGF0ZV9lZGl0P3RlbXBsYXRlTmFtZT13eWh0ZXN0MyZpZD02MzU5ZTM1ZDEwNjVlNjJmOTkzZTVjNGMmdGltZVJhbmdlPXsidGltZUZpZWxkIjpudWxsLCJiZWdpbiI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiYWJzb2x1dGUiLCJ1bml0IjpudWxsLCJ2YWx1ZSI6MTU0NjI3MjAwMH0sImVuZCI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiYWJzb2x1dGUiLCJ1bml0IjpudWxsLCJ2YWx1ZSI6MTU1MDU5MjAwMH19JnJlcG9ydE5hbWU9d3lodGVzdDNfJUU2JTlDJTg4JUU2JThBJUE1'
```

If you have any idea,please make a comment,I need your help.